# Amazon music not working in chrome (firefox works)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, music, amazon

I subscribed to amazon music and like the service. However, the web streaming does not work in the chrome browser. It does work in firefox. I use all current version, and tried it on two different ubuntu systems (kubuntu 17.04 and ubuntu 16.10).

The web page works but when I click play it keeps loading the song forever.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem until I found a little notification on the right side of the URL bar that plugins were blocked. Just tell it to execute all plugins and it should work. It's annoying, but I think better than installing another flash plugin version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you describe with chromium on Fedora and it started working for me once I had downloaded PepperFlash from https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ (choosing the linux 64-bit PPAP .tar.gz version) and extracted it to `/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/PepperFlash/`.

This probably won't be a direct fix for you since chrome should come with PepperFlash on its own, but maybe it will help you find a solution (I would just have commented, but do not have enough reputation).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had this problem with Chrome on a windows machine.  Amazon music would not play. Things looked like the song was continually loading, but never starting. I turned off ALL of my extensions on Chrome. (three dot icon on rt of menu bar, pick settings...three line icon on left w/ Settings...pick extensions.  Then slide the little button for each extension to the left to turn it off but not remove it)  Restart Chrome and try Amazon Prime Music again.  Mine then worked fine.  I turned the extensions back on until I found the one causing the problem.  For me it was "Disable HTML5 autoplay".

Comment: Don't have enough rep on AskUbuntu to add to Bill Anderson's answer but I'd been fighting the same problem in Firefox 52 ESR in Linux 4.9 and my workaround was to use an User Agent switching add-on to impersonate a Mac. I changed `media.autoplay.enabled` to `true` (which is the default value) and `media.block-autoplay-until-in-foreground` to `true` to keep some amount of autoplay prevention and now Amazon Music works as expected. Thanks Bill!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is probably caused due to an extension in Chrome. It worked for me in **incognito mode** as all extensions will be disabled by default in incognito mode. Hope it helps.